# What is the function of the pericope concerning the unknown man of God in 1 Kings 13?

Tags: 1-kings

1 Kings 13 contains the story of the unknown man of God who cries out against the altar Jeroboam had constructed. Although tasked with returning another way and neither eating nor drinking anything, he is intercepted by another (old) prophet who seemingly lies to him. This old prophet then cries out against the man of God. The story ends with the unknown prophet dying and the old prophet burying his bones.

I’ve noticed some elements of chiastic structure in the story. Parallelism including:

- “bones” and “altar”
- “Cried out”
- “Eat bread or drink water”
- “saddled the donkey”

The center of this seems to be vv.21:

> You have defied the word of the Lord and have not kept the command the word of the Lord gave you.

Along with the parallelism, the immediately preceding story is linked to the golden calf of Exodus through the usage of (obviously) “golden calves” but also the statement, “Here are your gods, Israel, who brought you up out of Egypt” (12:28).

My question is about the purpose and placement of this story which interrupts the narrative of the splitting kingdom. Why is it here and what function is it contributing to the narrative?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that the OP has largely answered his own question concerning 1 Kings 13.  The pericope provides the following for the overall narrative/story:

- an emphasis that obeying the importance of obeying the command of God in all situations as V21 explicitly states, and, as the OP has already listed

However, I believe we can see further functions of this story:

- it provides a personal illustration of what was going on nationally - the northern kingdom was separating itself from God by its disobedience and this story at a personal level illustrates this.  That is, disobedient nations are composed of disobedient individuals. [Hollywood makes frequent use of this dramatic device!!]
- it shows that prophets are just as human as the rest of us; that is, prophets are not immune to sin.  [Balaam in Num 22-24 also illustrates this point.]
- despite the failure of the dead prophet in this instance, he was still honored in death for the good he had achieved in the rest of his life.

Answer (score 1):

The OP states: "My question is about the purpose and placement of this story which interrupts the narrative of the splitting kingdom." My answer in a nutshell: The passage serves as a backstory to explain the later description of King Josiah's burning human bones on the altar at Bethel. Although the Man of God later sinned, Josiah honored him for predicting that he, Josiah, would destroy Bethel's altar.

2 Kings 23

> 16 When Josiah turned and saw the graves there on the mountainside, he
> ordered the bones taken from the graves and burned on the altar, and
> thus defiled it, according to the Lord’s word proclaimed by the man of
> God as Jeroboam stood by the altar on the feast day. When the king
> looked up and saw the grave of the man of God who had proclaimed these
> words, 17 he asked, “What is that marker I see?” The people of the
> city replied, “The grave of the man of God who came from Judah and
> proclaimed the very things you have done to the altar in Bethel.” 18
> “Let him be,” he said, “let no one move his bones.” So they left his
> bones undisturbed together with the bones of the prophet who had come
> from Samaria.

For scholars of the historical-critical school, the interruption in the narrative of 1 Kings 13 is explained by an editor inserting the story into that earlier narrative in order to provide the reason for Josiah's behavior:

1 Kings 13

> He cried out against the altar by the word of the Lord: “Altar,
> altar, thus says the Lord: A child shall be born to the house of
> David, Josiah by name, who shall slaughter upon you the priests of the
> high places who burn incense upon you, and they shall burn human bones
> upon you.” 3 He also gave a sign that same day and said: “This is the
> sign that the Lord has spoken: The altar shall be torn apart and the
> ashes on it shall be scattered.”

For source critics, the precise knowledge displayed by the unnamed prophet is an obvious clue that this story is back-dated into the narrative. For those who believe that the Bible is inerrant, it is proof positive of miraculous foreknowledge given to the prophets by God.

In either case, the narrative provides a basis for understanding why Josiah protected the bones of the unnamed prophet while desecrating those of the others. @Dottard's answer deals adequately with the other points of the OP.